# LINQ ordering by highest value per unique value in a certain column

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to figure out how to select the leading bids in a table called bids using linq.

The results needs to take the highest bid for each unique userId and display that ordered by bidValue

bids table:

```
bidId 1, userid 1, bidValue = 10
bidId 2, userid 2, bidValue = 20
bidId 3, userid 3, bidValue = 20
bidId 4, userid 1, bidValue = 30
bidId 5, userid 2, bidValue = 40
bidId 6, userid 1, bidValue = 50
```

outcome:

```
bidId 6, userid 1, bidValue 50
bidId 5, userid 2, bidValue 40
bidId 3, userid 3, bidValue 20
```

Comment: I think your second line was supposed to be userid 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - writing a query with distinct and orderby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235604/linq-writing-a-query-with-distinct-and-orderby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
var query = (from bid in context.Bids
            group bid by bid.userid into bidg
            select new
            {
               bidId = bidg.OrderByDescending(b => b.bidValue).First().bidid,
               userid = bidg.Key,
               bidValue = bidg.Select(b => b.bidValue).Max()
            }).OrderByDescending(b => b.bidvalue);
```

Comment: in the outcome sample, the order is by user id

Comment: I might be wrong, but I read it differently. I thought he wants it ordered by bidValue